# Comparing same value against numerous others in an if-statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This one is probably fairly straightforward, but I haven't succeeded in finding an answer as of yet. Anyway, what I want to do is compare one value against a group of others, and run the script if it matches one of them. Here's the verbose version of I want to do, which works fine, but I'm assuming there's a smarter, less verbose way to achieve this?

```
function updatePosition(e) {
    if((e.target.innerHTML == 1) || (e.target.innerHTML == 4) || 
      (e.target.innerHTML == 7)) {
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the `innerHTML` property is a string, you’ll need to convert it to a number to use the `indexOf` solution in the linked duplicate: `if ([1, 4, 7].indexOf(+e.target.innerHTML) !== -1)`. The unary `+` operator converts a value to a number.

Comment: hey @Ryan ! what's the plus in front of the e.target for?

Comment: @Argee: Half or more of my comment is a description of what the plus is

Comment: awesome, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Ryan!

Answer (score -1):

You can store all the valid comparison inside an array. Then you can use `Array#Find()` to get a matching value. If there is no matching value, you will get `undefined`

```js
function updatePosition(num) {
  let validNumbers = [1,4,7];
  console.log(validNumbers.find(valid => valid === num));
}

updatePosition(4);
updatePosition(9);
```

Comment: Why use `find` when you can use `includes` or `indexOf`? This also breaks on the value `0`, if you use it as a truthiness value like the question requires.

Comment: @Ryan OP is comparing `e.target.innerHTML`. If he find it, he uses `e.target.innerHTML` inside `console.log()`. Using `find()` allows OP to directly use the value if he finds it. `includes` or `indexOf` will just tell him that he finds it.